# Android http post works with string but not xstream

Tags: android, http-post

I'm making a droid app that uses a web service.  I have it working when I pass in a string, but when I try and use Xstream it doesn't work.  I have printed out the xml strings from both the Xstream and my own and they are identical.  Without xstream it looks like this and works

```
`HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://softeng.cs.uwosh.edu/students/cs342g6/login.php");
        Boolean response = false;
        try
        {

            String test = "<Login>" +
                    "<password>" + "lernrane" + "</password>" +
                    "<user_name>" + "jake@jake.com" + "</user_name>" +
                    "</Login>";

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(test,
                    HTTP.UTF_8);
            se.setContentType("text/xml");
            httppost.setEntity(se);
            System.out.println("MADE IT TO RESPONSE");
            HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = httpresponse.getEntity();
            String resp = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            System.out.println(resp);
            response = convertToBool(resp);`
```

But when I use xstream it looks like this and fails

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://softeng.cs.uwosh.edu/students/cs342g6/login.php");
        Boolean response = false;
        try
        {
            LoginObject login = new LoginObject();
            login.setUserName("jake@jake.com");
            login.setPassword("lernrane");
            XStream xstream = new XStream();
            xstream.alias("Login", LoginObject.class);
            String xml = xstream.toXML(login);
            System.out.println(xml);


            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(xml,
                    HTTP.UTF_8);
            se.setContentType("text/xml");
            httppost.setEntity(se);
            System.out.println("MADE IT TO RESPONSE");
            HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = httpresponse.getEntity();
            String resp = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            System.out.println(resp);
            response = convertToBool(resp);
```

My web service looks like this

```
 $dom = new domDocument;
 $dom = simplexml_load_file('php://input');
 $xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
 $user = Users::find_by_user_name($xml->user_name);

 if($user)
 {
if($user->password == $xml->password)
{
    echo "TRUE";
}
 }
 else 
     echo "FALSE";
```

Ignore the odd looking query, I am using active record and I know it works correctly...thanks

Comment: I should probably clarify... it returns false and doesn't crash

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out... When I printed out my xml user_name looked like this user__name eventhough it was clearly named user_name.  There must be some type of char set conflict so I just renamed it without the underscore.